# Long running process to get ip working async in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, ip

I need to call a javascript program which will get the ip address (from intranet) and send it to node js server where i have to do some calculation!

below is the `JS` file `ipaddress.js`:

```
var myIP = (function () {
    return {
        getIP: function () {
            var ip_dups = {};

            //compatibility for firefox and chrome
            var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

            //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
            if (!RTCPeerConnection) {
                //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                //
                //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                //
                var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                    || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            }

            //minimal requirements for data connection
            var mediaConstraints = {
                optional: [{ RtpDataChannels: true }]
            };

            var servers = { iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com" }] };

            //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
            var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

            function handleCandidate(candidate) {
                //match just the IP address
                var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

                //remove duplicates
                if (ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                    return (ip_addr);

                ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
            }

            //listen for candidate events
            pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) {

                //skip non-candidate events
                if (ice.candidate)
                    handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
            };

            //create a bogus data channel
            pc.createDataChannel("");

            //create an offer sdp
            pc.createOffer(function (result) {

                //trigger the stun server request
                pc.setLocalDescription(result, function () { }, function () { });

            }, function () { });

            //wait for a while to let everything done
            setTimeout(function () {
                //read candidate info from local description
                var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

                lines.forEach(function (line) {
                    if (line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                        handleCandidate(line);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
})(myIP() || {})
```

In angular program `app.component.ts` file:

```
import 'ipaddress.js'
declare var myIP;

....

ngOnInit(){
    ip = myIP();
    console.log(ip);
    //send this ip to node server and do the validation!
}
```

I need `myIP()` function to return ip and program should wait until myIP() doesnot send result and then only further execution starts.

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I don't know whether it would solve the problem but shouldn't you be exporting the `myIP` function from that JS file and importing it properly where you want to use it?

Comment: @tanmay can you explain how?

Comment: export using `module.exports` (you can look up exact syntax) and import the `myIP` function like `import { myIP } from ipaddress` (again lookup exact syntax)